# Send and read multiple requests/responses in Python with socket and gevent

Tags: python, sockets, asynchronous, gevent, spawn

I have synchronous implementation of sending multiple requests and receiving multiple responses with sockets in Python:

```
# ATTENTION, SYNCHRONOUS WAY

import socket
from select import select
import ssl

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 443
headers_with_body = 'HEADERS_AND_BODY_HERE'

s_ = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s_, ca_certs='/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/cacert.pem', cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)

sock.connect((host, port))

for i in range(10):

    readable, writable, exceptional = select([sock], [sock], [], 0)

    if readable:
        data = sock.recv(4096)
        print 'Received request'
        print data

    if writable:
        print 'Sending request'
        sock.sendall(headers_with_body)
```

This code works just fine, but it's asynchronous. So when i'm trying to send many requests to busy server it's blocking and I cannot send more than 10 requests in 1 second.

I have found that we can turn it in asynchronous with gevent, so I changed little bit my client's code:

```
# ASYNCHRONOUS WAY

import socket
from select import select
import ssl

import gevent
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 443
headers_with_body = 'HEADERS_AND_BODY_HERE'

s_ = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s_, ca_certs='/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/cacert.pem', cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)

sock.connect((host, port))

for i in range(10):

    readable, writable, exceptional = select([sock], [sock], [], 0)

    if readable:
        data = sock.recv(4096)
        print 'Received request'
        print data

    if writable:
        jobs = [gevent.spawn(sock.sendall(headers_with_body)) for i in xrange(100)]
        gevent.joinall(jobs)
```

This code seems to work well (doing the supposed job - sending 1000 request in parallel but I can't read the responses of each request).

Someone could help me to figure it out? I could say that i'm a newbie in Python so please help me to find the easiest way to send in 1 or 2 seconds at least 1000 requests in parallel (and receive 1000 responses).

Just consider that the target server could be busy in the moment of sending, so the responses may arrive with delay.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using async.io ?

Comment: @Illusionist, thanks for your interest. Yes, I've tried it but due it's too difficult to understand I was able only send in parallel bunch of GET requests but don't know how to implement posting XML data, using HTTPS etc...

I can use only 1 concurrent connection to the target server, so at exact moment I need to send 1000 requests, but before I need to maintain the keep-alive connection and send all these requests only at the end of the session.